# count() function + derived table and Group - making it all work

Tags: mysql, count, sum, having-clause, derived-table

Could someone please give me a hand in explaining in this example where the SUM function would go?  I am trying to get a literal count on the number of returned columns, NOT the number of meta_key's for each post id. I want a number like there are 5 results AFTER it groups.

```
SELECT nmbr, post_id
     , DeliveryDate
     , DeliveryType
  FROM ( SELECT nmbr, post_id
              , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_1' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) as DeliveryDate
              , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_2' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) as DeliveryType
           FROM wp_postmeta
         GROUP 
             BY post_id 
       ) AS derived_table
       
 WHERE DeliveryDate >= CURRENT_DATE
   AND DeliveryType = 'delivery'
```

I have tried but it doesnt count or sum anything and there is something about the HAVING clause that causes no results to return. If I remove that it shows all results on the table but its not counting them.

```
SELECT
    post_id,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_1' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_2' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryType
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY
    post_id
HAVING
    DeliveryDate >= CURRENT_DATE AND
    DeliveryType = 'delivery';
```

Here is an image of what the above produces [image: image of what this above clause does. It seems to be counting the meta_key results of each with a post ID that matches. It is not groping them when set up this way]

Comment: What is *a literal count on the number of returned columns*? Sample data, current and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: @GMB Have to return the meta data values with the CASE then group. Then I want to count. The above is actually all there is on this query. This isnt truncated. Just added more details

Comment: re "count on the number of returned columns" returned by what?  please add sample data and show your desired results for that data

Comment: How do I add sample data?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT nmbr, post_id
     , DeliveryDate
     , DeliveryType
  FROM ( SELECT nmbr, post_id
              , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_1' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) as DeliveryDate
              , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_2' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) as DeliveryType
           FROM wp_postmeta
         GROUP 
             BY post_id 
       ) AS derived_table
       
 WHERE DeliveryDate >= CURRENT_DATE
   AND DeliveryType = 'delivery'
   ) AS q
```